# Login with SSH public key doesn't work

Tags: linux, ssh, login, sshd, public-key

So I have my home computer, and my server. I'm trying to login to my server with my private key.

On my server say I have the user `serveruser`, to which I login from my home computer using

```
ssh -Y serveruser@myserver.com
```

And at my home computer, I have the user `homeuser` on my home computer.

So now, I want to login to the server using my private key. For that, I already have a key with passphrase in `/home/homeuser/.ssh/`. So I took the public key (id_rsa.pub), and copied it to my server at `/home/serveruser/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Now I would like to login using that key, so I tried to login using

```
ssh -Y serveruser@myserver.com
```

and it still asks me for the password, and not the passphrase.

I tried also logging in using

```
ssh -i /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_rsa -Y serveruser@myserver.com
```

and I'm still being asked for the user password.

What did I do wrong? Please advise.

Thank you for any efforts.

EDIT: According to Mason Heller's recommendation, I executed ssh-add, but it still insists that I input the password for serveruser@myserver.com.

EDIT: Information from `ssh -v -Y myserver.com` (personal information modified for anonymity).

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to myserver.com [100.100.100.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA b2:1a:68:21:5a:72:c4:f7:ec:ea:60:12:e4:f8:b5:71
debug1: Host 'myserver.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/homeuser/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: email@emailhost.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

More information:

cat /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

```
--removed for security--
```

/home/serveruser/.ssh/authorized_keys

```
total 4
-rwx------ 1 serveruser serveruser 400 Jan 26 01:09 id_rsa.pub
```

cat /home/serveruser/.ssh/authorized_keys

```
cat: /home/serveruser/.ssh/authorized_keys: Is a directory
```

Comment: What are the permissions on ``~serveruser/.ssh``? Some implementations enforce that the folder and its contents are only accessible by the user (i.e. ``drwx------`` or ``-rw-------`` respectively). If SELinux is installed on myserver.com (check with ``which setenforce``), ``restorecon -Rv ~serveruser/.ssh`` is also a thing to run. (if this works, I’ll post it as an answer)

Comment: You should run `ssh` with one or more options `-v` passed to it, to see whether it loads your private key and tries to offer it for authentication to the server. Pasting it here may offer other people more clues to answer your question.

Comment: @JonasWielicki that didn't work... please check the verbose output.

Comment: @eldering done, please check the output.

Comment: Please show us the following `cat /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, `ls -l /home/serveruser/.ssh/authorized_keys`, `cat /home/serveruser/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: @Marki done, please check the output.

Comment: See, /home/serveruser/.ssh/authorized_keys should be a _file_. You create it by merely adding the contents of id_rsa.pub to it (i.e. `cat  /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys`). (Obviously you have to copy the public key to the server first.) Now just having you execute those commands should have made you think why `cat` didn't work ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/home/serveruser/.ssh/authorized_keys` should be a file.

You create it by adding the contents of id_rsa.pub to it (i.e. cat /home/homeuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys).

(Obviously you have to copy the public key to the server first.)

Comment: Thank you! It works now. But it doesn't ask me for the passphrase... is that normal? I expected that it would ask me for the passphrase every time I log in. And one more question, how can I add more public keys? should I separate them with a new line?

Comment: If no passphrase is asked you probably already played with `ssh-agent` (make sure it doesn't run or logoff/login again). Unless you created a key without a passphrase (it will not say `Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
` or so when looking at the private key). And yes, you add them by adding new lines to the file. You should probably take a look at `man ssh`, especially the "AUTHENTICATION" section.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your keypair, you may want to run ssh-agent to handle the authentication.

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
```

Then your keypair will be available for all subsequent ssh sessions in that terminal. `ssh-agent` adds environment variables in your terminal session, which you need for `ssh` to use it. I typically run `ssh-agent > ~/.ssha; . ~/.ssha; ssh-add` in one pty, then `source ~/.ssha` in any others where I need to use ssh, so that all of my ptys can use the agent.
Also, I find it easier to use `ssh-copy-id` to add my public key to servers. It may make your life easier, too. :)

Comment: Although `ssh-agent` makes key management easier, it is by no means necessary to allow public key authentication. Without it, `ssh` will by default already try to authenticate with a private key `~/.ssh/id_rsa` if available and ask for its passphrase if necessary.

Comment: You need not use `ssh-agent`.