# No supported authentication methods available public key

Tags: linux, ssh

I have school project server - debian 8 jessie and I have working SSH Key-based authentication. My problem is, that I created new user named tester and he is unable to connect to server and it give the following error:

> No supported authentication methods available public key

I tried to change testers key to my own and then I tried to connect as tester by myself but it doesn't work.

I'm really newbie to this, so i have no clue what is wrong. I will be happy for any advices.

I used these commands

```
useradd -G users,sudo tester
passwd tester
mkdir /home/tester
mkdir /home/tester/.ssh
chown tester:tester /home/tester
chown tester:tester /home/tester/.ssh
chmod go-rx /home/tester
chmod go-rx /home/tester/.ssh
mv /home/marm04/authorized_keys /home/tester/.ssh
chown tester:tester /home/tester/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login with SSH public key doesn't work](http://superuser.com/questions/707142/login-with-ssh-public-key-doesnt-work).  I assume the server has the private key on it?  I went ahead and fix your grammatical mistakes.  Please spend more time doing that yourself in the future.

Comment: Yes server has the private key. Im sorry for my grammatical mistakes.

Comment: Does it have the public key?  Provide us the output to: `ls -l //home/tester/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 tester tester 396 Sep 30 13:46 //home/tester/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: I need the output to whatever command, will list all the keys, you currently have installed on the server.

Comment: Well i dont know what command does that, I'm really newbie to linux and putty, but the key tester has in his .ssh folder is this one.

ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAhLLZ1CViTAF5LZ+dEbzjJui7UDfK/XDTyBiNJnNFynIuxnoyz6Imbi5DEfdIWEgc2npZMFhLf3ndnElzaxtWzr9nGR6YQHL0qp6lXn+dpX5DyM1NVynw/nyyJKHBGfeO3zPW15jnjGf+jh6SfdLX1QzoNdH6unFZetGJHFNWFpH6fGnNu8wt2UJ9tJJuyxacozcoBUrAWcofbqXmJZBWoy+FcSHBVLoMKANuc8dlLGu8g+pn625DD/s4YRM2IcgWgq6crTWdDs9qUr7qkxKPTi+LYqXIq5Pqbm8cOQdj3NFUXNUnHDrLzZHCQt7D7pFTLRisv3wZ98V1ZP5yefVV0Q== xngup10_pa_1245

Comment: Appears you only have a single key, which I assume is the one key, that is currently working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are "doing it wrong", and there is more then 1 problem here, so lets work through them.

1. ~username/.ssh/authorized_keys needs to have a list of keys which can
   authenticate as that user.     So if both you and him are wanting to log
   in as him, this is possible.   You need to put both your public keys in
   the authorized_keys file - 1 key per line.   W**hen you log in using your
   key, you still log in as username@ip**  (ie his username, not yours.
2. I note that you moved "marm04" key to his account.  Assuming you are
   marm04, that is a mistake, you want to copy or cat it, so, assuming
   you already have his key there, the command to use would be 
   cat ~marm04/.ssh/authorized_keys >> ~tester/.ssh/authorized_keys
3. You should also check /etc/ssh/sshd_config and make sure that there is
   no line starting "AllowUsers", or, if there is, you will need to adjust
   it so he (and maybe his IP depending on how its written) can log in, 
   and then restart SSHD.
4. You need to be a bit careful with what you are doing with permissions.
    It looks like you have made the directory executable, and changed its
    permissions, but you have not changed the permissions on the authorized_keys file.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it.
I checked /var/log/auth.log and i found this line

```
2016-12-08T00:35:40.869224+01:00 info auth sshd[1554]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/tester
```

So i ran this command

```
chmod 755 /home/tester
```

and it works now. It is really stupid mistake. I hope it will help someone else in the future who will be as desperate as am I.